# How to get the result of difference between two date using php?

Tags: php, date

I have this `php` code

```
$today_date = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
$Expierdate = '09/06/2017 21:45:03';
$remaindate = date_diff($today_date,$Expierdate);       
echo $remaindate;
```

and i need result from difference between two date.

Comment: The difference wouldn't be a date; it would be years, days, hours, minutes, seconds. I would rename `$remaindate` to `$remaintime`

Comment: ... and see mike's answer at that page

Comment: guys how can i edit this question to got positive? i banned from ask questions!

Comment: @ObadaDiab You should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [SO META: Banned from asking questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date_diff()` needs a DateTimeInterface as an argument. In other words, you need to create a DateTime object first, using `new DateTime()` as shown below.

```
$today_date = new DateTime();
$Expierdate = new DateTime('09/06/2017 21:45:03');
$remaindate = $today_date->diff($Expierdate);
echo $remaindate->format('%a days');
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/qcj03)

The above would output

> 90 days

Because today is June 8th, and the format `09/06/2017` is September 6th - because you're using American format (`MM/DD/YYYY`).

If you ment June 9th (tomorrow), you need to use European format (`MM-DD-YYYY`, note the dash instead of slash). You can alternatively use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to create from a set format, so your current format, 09/06/2017, is interpreted as June 9th. The code would then be

```
$today_date = new DateTime();
$Expierdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '09/06/2017 21:45:03');
$remaindate = $today_date->diff($Expierdate);
echo $remaindate->format('%a days');
```

Output ([live demo](https://3v4l.org/s4BRj))

> 1 days

In any case, `$remaindate` holds some properties which can be used (see the manual), or you can format it to your liking by supplying the desired formation into the `format()` method.

- [`new DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)
- [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)
- [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/ro/dateinterval.format.php)
- [`DateTime::create_from_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: Probably better to use `DateTime::createFromFormat` for the expire date as I assume that date is supposed to be `09-Jun` (`day/month`) instead of what DateTime expects which would return `06-Sep` (`month/day`).

Comment: That is true, the format given in the original answer is in American format (MM/DD/YYYY). I'll edit in a note about it.